# SquarePointOfSaleSDK crash on Run - image not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, square-connect

After finally getting all this installed I'm getting this error.  "image not found".  I'm Sure it's something I did!

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SquarePointOfSaleSDK.framework/SquarePointOfSaleSDK
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A23CD8ED-6533-46C9-9039-3540379A4D6F/Version 10.app/Version 10
  Reason: image not found

Comment: How are you integrating the SDK?

Comment: We added the SquarePointOfSaleSDK.xcodeproj to our project "Version10.5" and set it up as the Target Dependency then added the framework.  It finds the SquarePointOfSaleSDK and everything compiles fine.  This is the first time  we have added another project to our project.  Our targets don't look like your Test Project which is a bit confusing as it looks like the project is dependent on itself??

Answer (score 3):

You need to also add `SquarePointOfSaleSDK.framework` to the Embedded Binaries section on the General tab of your target settings.
[image: Embedded Binaries section]

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  Figured there was just one thing that I was missing and that was it!